# codeigniter angular ajax file uploading return null value of file

Tags: angularjs, ajax, codeigniter, file, uploading

### Ajax file uploader using angular codeigniter return null value of file data

```js
$http({
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'add',
 headers: {'Content-Type': false,'data-type': 'json'},


 data: $scope.setting
 }).success(function (data) {
 console.log(data);
 $scope.messageEdit = data;
 $scope.message="";
 });
```

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="submitForm()">
    Select File To Upload:<br />
    <input type="file" name="st_logo" ng-model="setting.file" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"  class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

Comment: controllerpart: public upload function(){ $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");$data = json_decode($postdata); $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';$config['max_size'] = '2000'; $config['max_width'] = '2000';
 $config['max_height'] = '2000'; $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   if (!$this->upload->do_upload('st_logo'))

Comment: {    $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); }else { $upload_data = $this->upload->data();$data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . $upload_data['file_name'] . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>'; }}

Comment: Add more description of what are you expecting and whats happening. Also, adding code in comments does not look nice. Add them in the question itself.

Comment: `ng-model` won't get bounded to `file` type inputs. You may need a directive to get file data from `<input type="file"`

Answer (score 0):

I got an  answer

```js
var myFormData = new FormData();
 var photo=document.getElementById('st_logo');
 var file=photo.files[0];
 console.log(file.name+"   "+file.size);

myFormData.append("currency", $scope.setting.st_currency);
    myFormData.append('bgcolor', $scope.setting.st_billingbgcolor);
    myFormData.append('textcolor', $scope.setting.st_billingtextcolor);
 myFormData.append('logo',file );
```